# Is it possible to free Todd of his curse?

Tags: bloodstained-ritual-of-the-night

Somewhere in the game, you find Todd, the cursed barber. He claims he has to give 666 unique makeovers to be freed from his curse. Is it actually possible to free him, or is that just a story mechanism that exists to have a makeover NPC?

[image]

Comment: It doesn't appear to have a quest entry, so I'm assuming it's a story mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is just a story mechanism. There is no where near enough unique hairstyles to fulfil this requirement yourself.

Even if you included colour variants, you could only achieve 12 styles * 6 colours, which is 72 possible combinations.

I guess this is why it explicitly states "hairstyles", so that the curious user doesn't waste any time in trying all the possible combinations for overall makeovers. Which would be well over 100,000 combinations (I don't know how many eye colours there are to be more specific)